# Criando .httacess para wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, linux, apache, htaccess

Configurei um wordpress em uma hospedagem linux, preciso configurar para que a url do post ao invés de:

http://www.example.com/index.php/post

seja:

http://www.example.com/post

Pelo que li devo mecher no arquivo httpd.conf porém isso é impossivel pois estou hospedando o site.
Nesse link eles ensinam como editar o httpd.conf para esse problema:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/permalinks-without-indexphp-2?replies=1

Como criar um arquivo .htaccess ?
Tentei colocar o código:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Porém ao subir esse arquivo o site da um erro 500.
inseri o arquivo tanto na pasta www como na root, antes do www

Comment: Você colocou esse`.htaccess` no *mesmo* diretório que o wp?

Comment: Sim, no mesmo diretorio, dentro da pasta www/ porém da erro 500 no servidor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

código correto para o .htaccess

Para que o Wordpress não precise do /index.php/ nos links permantentes.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Criar no bloco de notas e salvar como:
[image: Como Salvar o .htaccess no notepad]